JOLT SPEC for Filtering on two Conditions
I have trouble finding the right Jolt Spec.
This is my Input JSON:
{
  "value": [
    {
      "identifier": "plm",
      "value": "3",
      "value_unit_key": "",
      "language": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "mytest",
      "value": "whatever",
      "value_unit_key": "",
      "language": ""
    },
   {
      "identifier": "new ",
      "value": "anything",
      "value_unit_key": "kg",
      "language": ""
    }
  ]
}  

This is my desired Output JSON
In every object where the identifier has the value 'plm' AND the value is '3', the value should be changed to 'active'.
All other information should remain unchanged.
{
  "value": [
    {
      "identifier": "plm",
      "value": "active",
      "value_unit_key": "",
      "language": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "mytest",
      "value": "whatever",
      "value_unit_key": "",
      "language": ""
    },
   {
      "identifier": "new ",
      "value": "anything",
      "value_unit_key": "kg",
      "language": ""
    }
  ]
}  

Here's my approach, but it doesn't yield the desired result.
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "*": {
          "value_unit_key": "value[#2].value_unit_key",
          "language": "value[#2].language",
          "identifier": {
            "plm": {
              "@(2,value)": {
                "3": {
                  "#active": "value[#1].value",
                  "#plm": "value[#1].identifier"
                }
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "identifier": "value[#2].identifier",
              "value": "value[#2].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

It does not return the original identifier and the original value if the AND-Condition is not fullfilled. The output is:
{
  "value": [
    {
      "identifier": "plm",
      "language": "",
      "value": "active",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "language": "",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "language": "",
      "value_unit_key": "kg"
    }
  ]
}

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Kind Regards
Katja

Welcome to SO Katja

You can convert the current shift transformation to this one :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the representative for the "value" array
        "*": { // for the indexes of the array
          "identifier": { // manage "identifier" and "value" within this node
            "plm": {
              "@2,value": {
                "3": {
                  "@(4,&3)": "&6[&5].&4", //for the "identifier" attribute
                  "#active": "&6[&5].value" //&6 reprsents the key "value"
                },
                "*": { // for other values of "value"
                  "@(4,&3)": "&6[&5].&4",
                  "@4,value": "&6[&5].value" // go up 4 levels to reach the
                    //level of the "value" attribute
                }
              }
            },
            "*": { // else case for "identifier" values
              "@(2,&1)": "&4[&3].&2", // reduce 2 levels for the each identifier 
              "@2,value": "&4[&3].value"
            }
          },
          "value": { "": "" }, //get rid of the current "value" attribute
          "*": "&2[&1].&" //all other attributes
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Anytime @KatjaBürger !

Excellent Solution @Barbaros Özhan. I think you probably can achieve simpler and more efficient spec if you start traversing values from the value field then the identifier vs identifier then value since you are only changing the value field value. This will remove the need for additional step to enforce the plm value and the step for getting rid of the extra value toward the end. My spec:  [{"operation": "shift","spec": {"value": {"": {"value": {"3": {"@(2,identifier)": {"plm":{"#active": "value[&5].&4"}}},"": {"$": "value[&3].&2"}},"*": "value[&1].&"}}}}]

@samersaleh: This is also an excellent solution, which works, of course.
I nearly understood how it works, but could you be so kind, to clarify the
following coordinates:
@(2,identifier), value[&5].&4, value[&3].&2
I know, that this is about going up the nodes, but I do not understand,
how it works in this case. Thanks in advance for your help.

@(2,identifier) means go up two level starting from level 0 for current level where this is specified in in  jolt spec. The jolt spec traverse the json structure starting from root level (value parent field) , going down the node which can be simple type field or complex type field (nested json) and finally ending with the leaf level which is the final value of a simple type field. If you look at where @(2,identifier) specified you noticed is down to the leaf level of value 3 of the field "value", so counting up 1 level is the value 3 but to get to the identifier field value I need...

to go one level more (to level 2) which makes me at the same level as the "value" field since both "value" & identifier fields at the same level in the input json. After getting the identifier value from level 2 I'm traversing its value to see if its equal "plm", and if its , then I'm assigning new value of "active" to the "value" field but maintain the same array structure under the parent value field, that is why Im starting with "value" on the right hand side and then opening square brackets [] for array and using &5 which if you could 5 level up in the jolt spec as:...

level 0 -> current level, level 1 -> plm value level, level 2 -> @(2,identifier) level, level 3 -> the value 3, level 4 -> value field & finally level 5 is the value array current index , since I need the index itself not its value I use & vs @. & means whatever the name in the Left Hand Side. So basically Im saying store the new "value":"active" under the current index where the original key\values are located , since original were located at index 0 of the input Jason, the new output will also be stored at index 0.

By the way its always recommend to avoid specifying the field names as much as possible to keep the spec as dynamic as possible, so instead of saying
"#active": "value[&5].&4"
I could write at as:
"#active": "&6[&5].&4"
If you count up to level 6 and use & which means the name of the field on the LHS which is in this case "value" which is same result but more dynamic.

For a beginner Like me it is of course easier to use the fieldnames…but I understand that this is not Dynamic…
